# xlrd throws TypeError: embedded NUL character when trying to open an `.xls` file from web in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, urllib, xlrd

I am trying to open an excel file from the web and extract one of the columns.  However, when I try to open the file with `xlrd` I get an error.  The code I am trying is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xlrd
DJIA_URL = 'http://www.djaverages.com/?go=export-components&symbol=DJI'
xlfile = urlopen(DJIA_URL).read()
xlbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlfile)
```

however, I am getting a type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\development\Pynance\pynance\sources\indices.py", line 31, in <module>
    xlbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlfile)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
TypeError: embedded NUL character
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

If I download the file manually and open it like:

```
xlfile = 'DJIComponents.xls'
xlbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlfile)
```

no problems, I would just rather skip the manual step.  Is there an encoding setting or something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd.open_workbook()` can only open excel files. However, the `xlfile` object created by `xlfile = urlopen(DJIA_URL).read()` is not an excel file, so `xlbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlfile)` won't open.

xlfile created by the above way was an object of class "bytes". The fact can be seen by the command

`print(type(xlfile))`

and that should give

`<class 'bytes'>`

Therefore, you must retrieve the file by

(1) adding

`import urllib.request`

(2) saving the excel file by

`urllib.request.urlretrieve(DJIA_URL, r'path\to\file\xxx.xls')`

(3) finally open it with

`xlrd.open_workbook(r'path\to\file\xxx.xls')`

(Tested on python 3.4 eclipse PyDev win7 x64.)

Comment: Thanks!  I was actually able to avoid explicitly saving the file by : `xl_file, headers = urlretrieve(DJIA_URL)` `xl_book = xlrd.open_workbook(xl_file)` since [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urlretrieve#legacy-interface), "The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (***if absent***, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name). " (emphasis mine).  Is there a different function for this instead of `urlretrieve` that isn't part of _legacy interface_?

Comment: I recommend moving to `urllib3`. Something like `my_pool = urllib3.PoolManager()`....`with my_pool.request('get', my_url, preload_content=False) as my_connection_obj, open(fname, 'wb') as my_file:`....`shutil.copyfileobj(my_connection_obj, my_file_out)` may save your file. (sorry for unable to typeset in a comment)  Moreover, you can even use `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` to create your own temporary file if you really don't like saving the file explicitly.